# home directory full

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, disk-usage

I'm relatively new to Linux.
My home directory is almost full, but I have the media directory which has about 2TB space free. I can't paste anything to this directory. Can anyone tell me how to use this space. My space usage is like below: The last one is that I want to use.

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks   Used  Available Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sda1       144286384  12371984  124585020  10% /
udev             65994148         4   65994144   1% /dev
tmpfs            13200588       924   13199664   1% /run
none                 5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
none             66002940       240   66002700   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda6        58632388    233824   55420160   1% /boot
/dev/sda7       200896520 171206124   19485368  90% /home
/dev/sdb1      1922859824    294652 1824889500   1% /media/f626cefe-8e59-4767-986a-32e282864a6f
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest thing to do (note: this will transfer your entire `/home/` to this drive.  This is far simpler, and also allows for creation of other users on this storage medium):

Assuming that /dev/sdb1 is formatted as ext4:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/f626cefe-8e59-4767-986a-32e282864a6f
sudo cp -r /home/* /media/f626cefe-8e59-4767-986a-32e282864a6f/
sudo mv /home /home.old
sudo mkdir /home
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.old
echo "/dev/sdb1              /home         ext4      defaults,noatime,user,auto      0      2" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo mount /dev/sdb1
```

Then check to see that everything is as it should be.  If so, then reboot and check again.  If all goes as it should you will have 2TB of `/home/` storage!  Once you have verified that everything is working as it should be, then and ONLY THEN can you run this commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /home.old /etc/fstab.old
```

If all goes well, you will be up and running in no time.  Depending on how large your `/home/` is, this could take an hour or more to copy over.

Comment: Instead of using the partition number you should use the UUID of the partition in fstab.

Comment: And why do you use `sudo` after a `sudo su -`

Comment: also, you don't need to use sudo su if you use sudo tee instead of sudo echo

Comment: Not familiar with sudo tee @mchid

Comment: Because I'm sleep deprived @A.B.

Comment: @daniel you can pipe `echo`  to `sudo tee -a` like that so that you don't have to use `sudo -`. It is quite important to note the use of the flag `-a` as the `-a` flag appends the text to the file. Without that flag, it will overwrite the entire file so don't forget that if you decide to use it in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You can `sudo mv` or `sudo cp` to the /media/f62...a6f directory if you just want the info there in storage (won't be modifying it a ton).

You can also modify your /etc/fstab and include a `user` option for the /dev/sdb1 entry. Then you, as a user, should be able to mount and modify anything in the directory. There are a lot of fstab options you can do that will set the permissions of the items.

This is an example of what I did for my backup drive:

`/dev/sdb1 /backup  ext4    defaults,user   0 0`

You might also try `sudo chown -R [yourusername]:[yourusername] /media/f62...a6f` and `sudo chmod -R 755 /media/f62...a6f` if the above options still prevent you from adding files.